# ¿Donde es almacenado el registro de la tabla sys.server_audits?

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera saber donde es almacenada la base de datos, el registro de las auditorias que coloco en la instancia de SQL Server.

Han borrado el objeto del servidor y quisiera saber si restaurando alguna de las bases de datos de sistema es posible obtener dicho registro.

Comment: sys.server_audits es una vista que tira de la base de datos msdb

Comment: Si está en la msdb en que tabla puedo encontrarlo? @Javifer2

Answer (score 0):

No es una tabla de ninguna base de datos.

Sys.server_audits es una vista que tiene la base de datos msdb

[image: Resultado Imagen]

No deberías de pensar en tocar las tablas del sistema. Como mucho restaurar la misma.

[Restaurar bases de datos del sistema](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-system-databases-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Eso lo entiendo y no quiero realizar ningun cambio. Sólo quiero restaurarla sin sobreescribir la existente. Quizas restaurarla con otro nombre msdb2 (por ejemplo). Y entonces consultar datos como la fecha en que se creo y la fecha en la que se modificó por ultima vez antes de borrarla. @javifer2

Comment: Para consultar, solo tienes que hacer una select sobre el nombre cualificado de 3 partes. Select * from [msdb2].Sys.Server_audits incluso puedes hacer un union all tal que Select 0 as bbdd, * from [msdb].Sys.Server_audits union all Select 1,* from [msdb2].Sys.Server_audits y observar las diferencias. Ten cuidado con los nombres de los ficheros al restaurar.

Comment: Ya lo he realizado y me muestra sólo los nombres de los objetos de auditoría actuales. Es como que independientemente de la base de datos que le coloque delante el motor del sql server asume que quiero traer los registros de la base de datos actual.@javifer2

Comment: Realmente ¿qué estás buscando?. Dices: registro de las auditorias que coloco en la instancia de SQL Server. Te refieres a las auditorias de login. Puedes modificar la pregunta y mostrar una captura de pantalla de donde. ¿Qué se supone que han borrado? Mas que nada porque en SQL server existen varias cosas que se llaman Auditoría. Para poder precisar un poco mejor.

Comment: Estoy buscando la fecha de creación y modificación de los objetos de auditoría creados previamente antes de ser borrados. Ojo: no me refiero a los logs de auditoría sino a los objetos en sí. Básicamente lo que quisera es saber cuales son las tablas que utiliza la vista sys.server_audits.

Comment: Estoy buscando la fecha de creación y modificación de los objetos de auditoría creados previamente antes de ser borrados. Ojo: no me refiero a los logs de auditoría sino a los objetos en sí. Básicamente lo que quisera es saber cuales son las tablas que utiliza la vista sys.server_audits. @javifer2